# UI Design/Development - Is there a feasible way of coding multidirectional gradients?

Tags: html, ios, css, linear-gradients

I've been browsing Dribbble this morning and [found this nice UI design](https://dribbble.com/shots/2631867-Starting-new-dating-app) for a dating app, see screenshot below:

[image]

Now, this is an ever growing trend in design and it does look fantastic, but realistically is it possible to code an element that has a horizontal/diagonal gradient *and* fades out vertically?

If I were to do this I would probably do it using only CSS, which is fine for the colour gradient, but is there a way to also fade the element out vertically. The only other way I can imagine doing this is to generate the gradient as an image on the fly using server side code but I'd imagine that would use a lot of server resources to regenerate on the fly.

Info on other ways of doing it would be great, I've tried a couple of ideas but nothing has actually worked yet.

Andy

Comment: Of course, use RGBA colors...

Comment: The dark blue to light blue gradient is diagonal, the fade to transparent is vertical. How would RGBA work with that?

Comment: Ah-ha, that's a good idea, so offset the centre point to the bottom left of the screen and adjust the size to create the effect above I assume?

Comment: That's probably the way I'd do it. As you say, there is no method of having gradients in two directions at once...you have to fake it. Unless you could do something with blend modes or masks but that seems like overkill.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I'll give it a go in my lunch break and post my results. Thanks for the ideas/discussion :)